# Binary fractional to hexadecimal error (turbo c)

Tags: c, binary, hex

I just revised this code to accept binary numbers with fractional part. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double binaryval, frac, z;
    long int hexadecimalval = 0, i = 1, remainder, num, p;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the binary number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &binaryval);
    num = binaryval;
    frac = binaryval - num;
    while (binaryval != 0)
    {
        remainder = num % 10;
        hexadecimalval = hexadecimalval + remainder * i;
        i = i * 2;
        binaryval = binaryval / 10;
    }
    printf("Equivalent hexadecimal value: %lX", hexadecimalval);
    printf(".");
    while (binaryval != 0)
    {
        while(frac != 0)
        {
            z = frac * 2;
            p = z;
            frac = z - p;
        }
        remainder = p % 10;
        hexadecimalval = hexadecimalval + remainder * i;
        i = i * 2;
        binaryval = binaryval / 10;
    }
    printf("%lX", hexadecimalval);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

so the problem is... it gives a totally wrong answer

SAMPLE OUTPUT:
Enter the binary number: 1111.1111
Equivalent hexadecimal value: FFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFF

And then I tried changing **'binaryval'** into **'num'** in this loop...

```
while (num != 0)
{
    remainder = num % 10;
    hexadecimalval = hexadecimalval + remainder * i;
    i = i * 2;
    binaryval = num / 10;
}
```

but it only lets the user input a binary number and nothing else. Also, I can't even return to my codes. It's kinda got "stuck" and I have to close my Turbo C to run it again.

Can someone please tell me what's the problem and the things that needed to be changed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of binary data could be 1111.1111. And why are you storing it to double????

Comment: #offtopic Is there a good reason to use Turbo C?

Comment: @LPs because binary `1111.1111` is a real number, same value as decimal `15.9375` but I suspect OP should be entering a string.

Comment: @WeatherVane For sure ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane how did you get 15.9375 exactly? Did you stuff those bits into an IEEE 754 float?  if so, how did you load the exp and mantissa?

Comment: @nerdistcolony, obviously the integral part is decimal 15 and here are two methods for the fractional part. 1) decimal `15/16 = 0.9375` because we have 15 shifted right 4 times. 2) binary `.1111` = decimal `1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 = 0.9375` (just as *decimal* `.1111` = `1/10 + 1/100 + 1/1000 + 1/10000`;)

Comment: @nerdistcolony I'm sorry but your answer gave me strange results.

Comment: This is like the third question I've seen using Turbo C in two days. Why is everyone still using Turbo C?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for you, it doesn't store very much internally as I examine the input by each character. The integral part is simple, just build the value. The fractional part is a bit more difficult, to align it correctly I have taken input 4 bits at a time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    long whole=0;
    int ch, fract=0, bits=0;

    // integral part is straight fowrard
    while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF && ch != '.' && ch != '\n') {
        switch(ch) {
            case '0':
                whole = whole * 2;
                break;
            case '1':
                whole = whole * 2 + 1;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Bad input\n");
                return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%lX", whole);

    // fractional part is more tricky to align correctly
    if (ch == '.') {
        printf(".");
        while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
            switch(ch) {
                case '0':
                    fract = fract * 2;
                    bits++;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    fract = fract * 2 + 1;
                    bits++;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Bad input\n");
                    return 1;
            }
            if (bits == 4) {            // process 4 bits at a time
                printf("%X", fract);
                fract = 0;
                bits  = 0;
            }
        }
        if(bits) {                          // deal with 1 to 3 trailing bits
            printf("%X\n", fract << (4-bits));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Your sample input and another:

```
1111.1111
F.F

1.000001
1.04
```

Comment: Can you describe or summarize how the basic operation and logic of translating binary 0.1111 to it's decimal equivalent?  That's 0x0.f = 0d0.15?

Comment: See comment in main section.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you need to change `binaryval` to `num` in your loops.